# How can I generate personalized URLs for each user on my website while tracking their usage?

Tags: url, redirect, web

New to web creation.

I am trying to create a website which is accessed by a different URL for each user. Meaning, I want to be able to generate different URLs and hand them to various people, with all URLs redirected to the same page. I would of course, like to retain the information from each URL, so I can tell which specific URL was invoked.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Could I decide that my URLs are always "my_website.com/id=some_number", and have this format always redirected to my website? This without creating an actual page for each id number, but somehow redirecting any given id to the same page (while saving the id number within my server).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you explain .
You can also use .htacess for this task.just search   about it you get tutorial about it